# Determine where an existing Excel macro is used

Tags: excel-2010

Is there any way to determine where in an Excel 2010 workbook a macro is used?  I inherited a workbook from a coworker and there are some macros with no comments for which I can't determine where they are used.  I'd like to delete them if they are just trial or debug related code that was left behind.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of the original file, delete the unwanted macros in the new file, then see if it still works....